# JSON RPC service using database codeigniter

Tags: jquery, mysql, json, codeigniter, rpc

I have a problem with my JSON RPC service. I make a class and put it output of application folder(I put it on service folder on root directory). This servis is class which I called by jQuery and use Ajax to response database results.
How do I access to database file which is put in
application/config/database.php 
Can you help me?

Comment: You access the database config with a FTP or SFTP program or use SSH. If you mean generate queries to the db, see http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/index.html

Comment: I want to connect with service to database which is on same server like web site. But, I want to leave this line "?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');" because security, but it do not allow me to include that file and read the settings needed to access to my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the database if it's not loaded already:

```
$this->load->database();
```

then call the configuration items:

```
$db['default']['hostname'];
$db['default']['username'];
//etc
```

---

Update

If you are looking to get these variables outside of the codeigniter application, define `BASEPATH` and include the file:

```
define('BASEPATH','');
include('/full/path/to/codeigniter/application/config/database.php');
```

then you can call the configuration items as shown above.

Comment: It do not work for me :( I give an error:"<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined property: Servis::$load in <b>D:\xampp\htdocs\ecarrent\servis\xxxxx.php</b> on line <b>16</b><br />
<br />

<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function database() on a non-object in <b>D:\xampp\htdocs\ecarrent\servis\xxxx.php</b> on line <b>16</b><br />".

CI application folder is renamed to ecarrent and service is put on servis folder on root project directory.

Comment: Looks like you are working outside of codeigniter.. I updated my answer.

Comment: Yes, I do. service is independent class. Thank you. Now it's work! Thank you so much!